# Nokia Here OverlayPanel in API-V3

Tags: here-api

The Nokia-Here API-V3 Documentation tells me, that it's possible to create and implement custom UI-controls like 'Button', 'Element','Container' etc on the map ...
I tried it out and anything works for me, except the H.ui.base.OverlayPanel.
I will create a little info-panel triggered by an info-button on the map.
The info-button is not the problem. the api tells me, that there is a method (OverlayPanel.pointToControl(control))
But is doesnt work for me. Can anybody help me? Thanks for answers and  sorry for my english ...

Answer (score 2):

The basic UI system is not documented very well but depending on what you want to do, you will have to create a control and add it to the UI.I fiddled around with it and figured out the following way to do it:

```js
//Usual setup lines...
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
//Usual setup lines...
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), defaultLayers.normal.map);
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

//OK, so now we have a UI.
//Next thing we'll need is a control
var myCustomControl = new H.ui.Control();
//Also an overlay panel
var myCustomPanel = new H.ui.base.OverlayPanel();
//When the panel is rendered, we add some stuff to it
myCustomPanel.renderInternal = function(el, doc) {
  el.innerHTML = "Oh, hi there!";
  el.style.color = "white";
};

//Also a button that opens the overlay panel on click
// and closes on next click
var myCustomButton = new H.ui.base.PushButton({
  label: "clickme!",
  onStateChange: function(evt) {
    //OK, button state changed... if it's currently down
    if (myCustomButton.getState() == "down") { //or: H.ui.base.Button.State.DOWN)
      //Make sure the panel is positioned right
      myCustomPanel.pointToControl(myCustomControl);
      //... and open
      myCustomPanel.setState("open"); //or: H.ui.base.OverlayPanel.OPEN
    } else {
      //... or close when button is not down
      myCustomPanel.setState("closed"); //or: H.ui.base.OverlayPanel.CLOSED
    }
  }
});
//Add the button and the panel to the control
myCustomControl.addChild(myCustomButton);
myCustomControl.addChild(myCustomPanel);
//Set the position of the control in the UI's layout
myCustomControl.setAlignment("top-right");

//And tadaah
ui.addControl("myCustomControl", myCustomControl);
```

Comment: hi @echom
sorry for the late answer. very great thanks. it was very helpful for me.
thanks, bernd